# Report Builder charts - grouping data by a specific age group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a pretty large dataset where learners are divided into age groups (16-18, 19+). I am trying to calculate the retention of learners (completed field/ Leavers field) and display the  chart by just one of those age groups (16-18). 
How can I do this as an expression?

Comment: This is the script I am using but it brings back zero whereas I am expecting around 1300 starts: =Sum(Fields!Starts.Value) AND (Fields!Age_Group.Value) = 16-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a calculated field where you can store the different age groups:

```
'Name: AgeGroups
=IIF(CInt(Fields!Age.Value) > 15 And CInt(Fields!Age.Value) < 19, "16-18", "19+")
```

Now add everything you need to your chart. The `Fields!AgeGroups.Value` is now the cathegory. In the chart properties under filter you can add the following filter, to display just one of the age group:

```
'Expression
=Fields!AgeGroups.Value

'Format
String

'Operator
=

'Value
16-18
```

This way if your custom grouping changes sometimes, you just need to apply the changes in the calculated field once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This I have already done but how do I get the calculation into the expression (completed field/ Leavers field)? I need to know the retention of all learners who are 16-18? The expression needs to have both criteria... must be 16-18 and then the calculation to return their retention

Comment: Just use the expression as chart data values: `=Sum(CDbl(Fields!Completed.Value)) / Sum(CDbl(Fields!Leavers.Value))`. This expression is your chart value. It gets filtered now and then summed up by your category.

Comment: Apologies, I totally forgot to mention that I am using Academic year (3 years) as my category. So it is, in actual fact, 3 different criteria. Academic year in the category, then the calculation in the expression for values

Comment: Thats no problem you can add as much categorys as you want, just wrap it in the `IIF()` statements. For example: `IIF(CInt(Fields!Age.Value) < 15, "Smaller 15", IIF(CInt(Fields!Age.Value) = 16, "Equals 16", "Bigger 16"))`